# Can I write a file to a specific cluster location?

Tags: delphi, filesystems, ioctl, delphi-10.3-rio, disk-io

You know, when an application opens a file and write to it, the system chooses in which cluster will be stored. I want to choose myself ! Let me tell you what I really want to do... In fact, I don't necessarily want to write anything. I have a HDD with a BAD range of clusters in the middle and I want to mark that space as it is occupied by a file, and eventually set it as a hidden-unmoveable-system one (like page file in windows) so that it won't be accessed anymore. Any ideas on how to do that ?

**Later Edit:**
I think [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_move_file) is my last hope. I just found it, but I need to investigate... Maybe a file could be created anywhere and then relocated to the desired cluster. But that requires writing, and the function may fail if that cluster is bad.

Comment: That is a very low-level operation. Best not to do it yourself, leave that to recovery tools that specialize in it.

Comment: I haven't met a recovery tool which is able to do this job, yet...

Comment: [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com) can recover data from bad clusters, and mark them as unwritable.

Comment: Why do you think that writing certain file to such sectors would solve your problem? modern OS'es are know for periodically checking contents of every file and by default also performing automatic defragmentation of every drive. This means that even if you write file to certain cluster there is no guarantee that such file will stay there. As others suggested the correct approach to solving your problems is to run some kind of disk scanning utility that is able to mark certain clusters as bad and thus preventing any programs to write any data to such clusters.

Comment: PS: I have even seen disk utilities who allow you to manually set certain disk cluster as being bad even thou in reality such cluster might be perfectly fine. I have even hear od computer viruses that mark certain clusters as being bad and then hide in them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to your specific question: "Can I write a file to a specific cluster location" is, in general, "No".

The reason for that is that the architecture of modern operating systems is layered so that the underlying disk store is accessed at a lower level than you can access, and of course disks can be formatted in different ways so there will be different kernel mode drivers that support different formats.  Even so, an intelligent disk controller can remap the addresses used by the kernel mode driver anyway.  In short there are too many levels of possible redirection for you to be sure that your intervention is happening at the correct level.

If you are talking about Windows - which you haven't stated but which appears to assumed - then you need to be looking at storage drivers in the kernel (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/).  I think the closest you could reasonably come would be to write your own Installable File System driver (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/_ifsk/).  This is really a 'filter' as it sits in the IO request chain and can intercept and change IO Request Packets (IRPs).  Of course this would run in the kernel, not in userspace, and normally this would be written in C and I note your question is tagged for Delphi.

Your IFS Driver can sit at differnt levels in the request chain.  I have used this technique to intercept calls to specific file system locations (paths / file names) and alter the IRP so as to virtualise the request - even calling back to user space from the kernel to resolve how the request should be handled.  Using the provided examples implementing basic functionality with an IFS driver is not too involved because it's a filter and not a complete storgae system.

However the very nature of this approach means that another filter can also alter what you are doing in your driver.

You could look at replacing the file system driver that interfaces to the hardware, but I think that's likely to be an excessive task under the circumstances ... and as pointed out already by @fpiette the disk controller hardware can remap your request anyway.

In the days of MSDOS the access to the hardware was simpler and provided by the BIOS which could be hooked to allow the requests to be intercepted.  Modern environments aren't that simple anymore.  The IFS approach does allow IO to be hooked, but it does not provide the level of control you need.

**EDIT** regarding suggestion by the OP of using [FSCTL_MOVE_FILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_move_file)

For simple environment this may well do what you want, it is designed to support a defragmentation process.

However I still think there's no guarantee that this actually will do what you want.

You will note from the page you have linked to it states that it is moving *one or more virtual clusters of a file from one logical cluster to another within the same volume*

This is a code that's passed to the underlying storage drivers which I have referred to above.  What the storage layer does is up to the storage layer and will depend on the underlying technology. With more advanced storage there's no guarantee this actually addresses the *physical* locations which I believe your question is asking about.

However that's entirely dependent on the underlying storage system. For some types of storage relocation by the OS may not be honoured in the same way. As an example consider an enterprise storage array that has a built in data-tiering function. Without the awareness of the OS data will be relocated within the storage based on the tiering algorithms. Also consider that there are technologies which allow data to be directly accessed (like NVMe) and that you are working with 'virtual' and 'logical' clusters, not physical locations.

However, you may well find that in a simple case, with support in the underlying drivers and no remapping done outside the OS and kernel, this does what you need.

Comment: The disk controller hardware doesn't remap anything... I made an application that read the exact cluster that is BAD. I read it many times... and it failed everytime, and that "smart and super intelligent drive" didn't remap anything ! What should I do more to convince it to remap that unfortunate miserable cluster ?!! If it sees that it can't be read anymore, what the hell is it waiting for ? Of course, these are rhetorical questions... The controller is  just dumb.

Comment: @MarusNebunu Disk controllers can be all sorts of things - fibre channel HBA adapters, SCSI RAID controllers, etc. and of course you could be running in a VM. Typically there's a "logical address" which the actual hardware can map to the hardware you're going to access but there's no guarantee to you of the actual physical place it accesses. High end storage can migrate the data physically between different disks and disk arrays without the OS being aware that it's happening.

Comment: About the Edit... I just want to make an app for my own system, a common laptop with a common HDD. I write software as a hobby only for my needs. I don't intend that this code works on every computer in this world. I have a simple HDD and no automatic defragmentation enabled. I read every sector of that disk and I make a map with the inaccesible sectors. If I could create some files there, that space will not be accessible again. It's just a temporary solution. It does'n have to be perfect. Unfortunately, my skills are not so advanced so that I can write drivers.

Comment: @MarusNebunu I think that for a simple case your idea may well give you some traction, but with the reading I did into how to use the function I could not find a 'guarantee' of thow the addressing is presented.  You may well find that it works in your case ... but you will need to be careful, if it goes worng you will almost certainly cause corruption to your files.  If you have a test environment that you can trash then I think ti would be a very interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you problem is to mark bad cluster, you don't need to write any program. Use the command line utility [CHKDSK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) that Windows provides.

I an elevated command prompt (Run as administrator), run the command:

```
chkdsk /r c:
```

The check will be done on the next reboot.

Don't forget to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk).

Comment: It may be the problem to mark a bad cluster, but here, in this question, the problem is how can I mark it creating a file in that region. `Chkdsk` doesn't mark anything. In fact, I think there is no such thing as marking a bad cluster in today Windows. The only app that really mark bad clusters was the ScanDisk from the Norton Utilities in the MS-DOS era...

Comment: IMO you are wrong, chkdsk detect and mark bad clusters so they won't be used by anyfile anymore. You must use /r command line option for that. Also please note that modern disk are intelligent and have an internal remapping feature that maps bad sectors to good sectors. You only see a bad sector at Windows level once the disk has exhausted his list or spare sectors. It is then time to change the disk because it already has a bunch of bad sectors: it is dying.

Comment: For some brand of disk, there are low level software that interact with the disk firmware and you are able to really reformat it (With those disks, windows format doesn't really format at the low level, it just build the file system structure). Which disk brand and model are you talking about?

Comment: This topic is better discussed in https://superuser.com/ (A StackOverflow parrallel site).